# I do not have have access to navigator.mediaDevices when the site is deployed. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, web-deployment, surge.sh

I am currently trying to use the WebRTC api and have everything working locally.
When I deploy to `surge.sh` I lose access to the `navigator.mediaDevices` object. How can I resolve this?

The following line of code is where I am having trouble with.

```
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: {mediaSource: 'screen'}});
```

I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDisplayMedia' of undefined
```

Comment: You need https. `navigator.mediaDevices` is only available in SecureContext now in Chrome and in the spec.

Comment: Ahhh. Thank you. I had read something similar to that and it was not clear what the solution was.

Comment: Glad it resolved your issue. Adding it as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need https.

`navigator.mediaDevices` is only available in SecureContext now in Chrome [74](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927230&can=1&q=getusermedia%20securecontext&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), Firefox [68](https://www.fxsitecompat.dev/en-CA/docs/2019/getusermedia-and-enumeratedevices-can-no-longer-be-used-on-insecure-sites), and in the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-main/getusermedia.html#idl-def-mediadevices), which means the object will be missing in insecure contexts (http).

Answer (score 0):

As [jib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918910/jib) answered, `navigator.mediaDevices` is not available when webserver uses HTTP scheme while not hosted on `localhost`, but with an exception in chrome/chromium:

```sh
$ chromium --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=http://WEBSERVER_FQDN:PORT_NUMBER
```

`--unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` command line option allows to loosen the restriction. It's useful for developing/debugging when HTTPS is not set up yet or you need to analyze raw unencrypted HTTP messages (i.e. wireshark).