# Why does navigator.mediaDevices work differently in localhost and server?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm currently working on a video chatting project. And it uses `navigator.mediaDevies`. It works OK and returns `MediaDevices` object in localhost, but when I deployed my project to a server, it returns `undefined`. I'm using Google Chrome v77. And of course it was the same browser both in localhost and server. How does `navigator.mediaDevices` work? I think it should return the same result in the same browser. But it works differently in localhost and production server. What should I do to make `navigator.mediaDevices` return `MediaDevices` object in server? (Tried Mozilla Firefox but it didn't work either)

Comment: Duplication of [I do not have have access to navigator.mediaDevices when the site is deployed. How do I fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56623954/i-do-not-have-have-access-to-navigator-mediadevices-when-the-site-is-deployed-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On localhost, the browser allows reduced security measures.  In particular, HTTPS is not required.

For any other origin, HTTPS is required to use the Media Devices API.  If you check your developer console, you'll undoubtedly see an error showing this.

Comment: Yes, `window.isSecureContext` returned true in `http://localhost` (even it was http) but returned false in `http` server. Thanks for your answer.